# how to update status in social networks separately using Socialauth in android

Tags: android, sharing, socialauth

```
My application have three Login/Logout  button and 3 sharing buttons.
I am able to log-in and log-out from the social networks using social auth.
```

**but I am not able to share or update status separately in social networks.**

```
Functionality
```

- User is  Login in my Facebook, linked-in and Twitter account .
- when user click on FBshare button. User status only updated to Facebook. 
     Not in other social networks(*Linked in and Twitter*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I need to make separate Authadapter object for every Social Networks.
I have maintained these 3 objects throughout the application and post msgs to separately social networks. 
Hopes it will helps anyone.
```